# Number of possible values for fourth side of quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, quadrilateral

> This math question is from KVPY SA 2009 exam :
>
> The sides of a quadrilateral are all positive integers and three of them are 5, 10, 20. How many values are possible for fourth side?
>
> Options: $\quad$ A. 29 $\quad$  B. 31   $\quad$  C. 32   $\quad$  D. 34

D option is the correct answer.

But when I tried to solve this by the method in picture (shared below) , I got 27 as answer with the values ranging from 7 to 33.
Please correct me where I am wrong.

[How I solved the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZimZ.jpg).

Comment: Firstly, $y$ may not be an integer. Secondly, there are other configurations of the sides besides the one in your diagram. What if, for example, $10$ and $5$ are swapped?

Comment: Well its mentioned in the question that all sides are integral

Comment: $y$ is not a side, it is a diagonal.

Comment: @player3236 Oh! yes, thanks for pointing out. Can you tell me of an alternate method to solve this problem?

Comment: Perhaps, use the generalized triangle inequality: the sum of lengths of the three other sides is more than the remaining side. However I don't see how the answer is D.

Answer (score 2):

You are assuming that $y$ must be an integer, but this is not stated in the problem.  It is necessary and sufficient that the longest side be greater than the sum of the other three sides.  If the longest side is $20$, we have $20<x+15$ so that $6\leq x\leq20$.  If $x$ is the longest side, we have $20\leq x<35$, so $6\leq x\leq 34$ and A is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Arrange $a = 20, b = 10, c = 5$ for maximum value through sum and min value through difference $(\ge 0$).

$a + b + c = 35$ which is the longest line segment using them.

$a - b - c = 5$ which is the smallest line segment using them.

So $6 \le x \le 34$ should form a quadrilateral.